# R programming: Difference between vectors

Tags: r, vector

Im trying to make a function in R such that 
if X is a vector and Y is a vector which is a subset of X, X and Y may contain a repeating elements, the X-Y contains the remaining elements(may still contain repeating elements). I try using `setdiff()` but I think its not applicable for repeating elements.
Ex.

```
d<-c(1,1,1,5,5,5,3,0,10,10)
b<-c(1,1,0)
e<-setdiff(d,b)
e
[1]  5  3 10
```

but it should be

```
c(1,5,5,5,3,10,10)
```

so i made a function

```
my.sample<-function(d,b){
  y<-numeric()
  u<-numeric()
  t<-list()
  x<-numeric()
  rd<-rle(d)
  rb<-rle(b)
  h<-numeric()
  d.data<-data.frame(rd$lengths,rd$values)
  b.data<-data.frame(rb$lengths,rb$values)

  for(i in 1:nrow(b.data)){
    y[i]<-b.data[i,2]
    u[i]<-b.data[i,1]
    h[i]<-(d.data[d.data$rd.values==y[i],1]-u[i])
    d.data[d.data$rd.values==y[i],1]<-h[i]
  }
  x<-d.data[,1]
  for(j in 1:length(x))
  {
    t[[j]]<-rep(d.data[j,2],x[j])        
  }
  return(unlist(t))        
}
```

so i  tried

```
my.sample(d,b)
[1]  1  5  5  5  3 10 10
```

so i think i made the right algorithm,, but when i tried using it to another more complicated vector like

```
x<-rpois(100,10)
y<-sample(x,25,replace=F)
my.sample(x,y)

Error in rep(d.data[j, 2], x[j]) : invalid 'times' argument
In addition: There were 21 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

there is sudden error and 21 warnings :(, can you guys give me hand please, by the way I'm a newbie in programming so please help me. Thanks

Comment: Not sure why you are keeping the first element from `d` and the result you provide is correct `(1,5,5,5,3,10,10)`. But, you could look at `%in%` operation on vectors. For ex: something like this `c(d[1], d[!(d %in% b)])`. the `!` mark arround `(d %in% b)` negates the TRUE/FALSE entries that indicate whether a particular element from d is present in b or not. I tried with `rpois` generated sample in your code and it appears to be working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another function:

```
f <- function(d, b) 
  d[-unlist(tapply(b, b, function(y) head(which(d == y[1]), length(y))))]    

# first example:
f(d, b)
# [1]  1  5  5  5  3 10 10

# second example:
set.seed(42)
x <- rpois(100,10)
y <- sample(x,90,replace=F)
f(x,y)
# [1] 11 12  9 10 10  9 10  4  9  6
```

Comment: Thank you sir, your all great help... :D  your solution is very clever and cool.. Thanks a lot @Sven Hohenstein

Answer (score 3):

Because you allow repeats you have a problem of recursion for which the easiest <strike>and most suitable</strike> solution is to use a `for` loop to loop over the elements of `b` and remove them from `d` one at a time using `match` which finds the first occurrence of a match only. This function also first checks that `x` is a subset of `y`:

```
f <- function(x,y){
  if( all( x %in% y ) )
    for( i in x ) y <- y[ -match( i , y ) ]
  return( y )
}

f(b,d)
#[1]  1  5  5  5  3 10 10
```

And using your second example...

```
set.seed(42)
x<-rpois(100,10)
y<-sample(x,25,replace=F)
f(y,x)
# [1] 11 12  9 10 10  9 10  4  9  6
```

Comment: @Your second example does not appear to be correct. I suppose you want `f(y,x)`.

Comment: Thank you sir, your solution is very friendly for as like me as new in R-programming.. Thanks a lot sir and to all, thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 2):

Edit: fastest yet of the posted answers:

```
carl2<-function(x,y) {
xfact<-as.numeric(names(table(xfoo)))
 tx<-table(xfoo)
 yfact<-as.numeric(names(table(yfoo)))
 ty<-table(yfoo)
 gotit<- ave(c(tx,ty),c(xfact,yfact),FUN=function(a) if(length(a)==2) a[1]-a[2] else a[1])
 gotx<-gotit[1:length(tx)]
 fakerle<-data.frame(values=as.numeric(names(gotx)),lengths=gotx)
 finalx<-inverse.rle(fakerle)
}
```

It's maybe 25% faster than the best benchmark below.  Ok, I'll stop this nonsense now.

Here's another approach:

```
Rgames> ds<-sort(d)
Rgames> db<-sort(b)
Rgames> ds[(length(db)+1):length(ds)]
[1]  1  3  5  5  5 10 10
```

That completely doesn't work, for obvious reasons.  My **favorite  tool** to the rescue:

```
Rgames> set.seed(1)
Rgames> x<-rpois(100,10)
Rgames> y<-sample(x,25,replace=F)
Rgames> rx<-rle(sort(x))
Rgames> ry<-rle(sort(y))
Rgames>  for(j in ry$values ) rx$lengths[which(rx$values==j)] <- rx$lengths[which(rx$values==j)] - ry$lengths[ry$values==j]
Rgames> 
Rgames>  newx<-inverse.rle(rx[rx$values>0])
Rgames> newx
 [1]  3  4  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  8
[23]  8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 11
[45] 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 13 13 13 13 13
[67] 13 14 14 14 14 14 15 15 16
```

Hope the OP doesn't care about the order of elements of the output!

EDIT, just to round out the thread, and now with the arguments in the proper order, sadly Simon no longer wins.   Oh, well.

```
Rgames>  microbenchmark(sven(x,y),simon(y,x),carl(x,y))
Unit: milliseconds
        expr        min         lq     median         uq        max
  sven(x, y)   1.724172   1.803495   1.858658   1.975400   2.073966
 simon(y, x) 104.202881 105.159258 105.928977 106.315333 190.408444
  carl(x, y)   1.705784   1.806489   1.845403   1.927078  22.150382
```

Comment: I'm not convinced this works. Try it on the second example? Perhaps I'm not translating it right....

Comment: @Simon- apologies -- of course it doesn't work. I'd need to collapse each value into a separate list element or something gross like that.

Comment: Ha ha. Ok have a +1 for imagination, but now you're using a `for` loop you might as well just use `match` (or even better Sven's cool solution)? Anyway, I spppose that's why you have `Rgames` as your prompt!! :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure mine is the slowest (but easy to understand - gotta count for something right?!). You have to swap the x and y round in my function to get the same result (best to check though) as you guys, i.e. `f(y,x)`.

Comment: oops,  reversing the x,y properly changes everything!

Comment: I also thinking to use the rle() but I use it badly :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d<-c(1,1,1,5,5,5,3,0,10,10)
b<-c(1,1,0)
d[!(d %in% b)]
```

Comment: I did. Sorry that my answer are not elaborated enough. And just saw the comment above that suggested the same idea.

Comment: Celio, Arun's point is that your code does not produce the required result.  Take a look at the output & compare w/ the OP's statement.

Comment: I see. As the comment above, at first I thought it should remove all instances of the shared elements.